# Ember.js: Determine current route from the view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have two routes, one for unread books and another for read books. Both routes share the same template:

```
App.UserPanelBooksIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  templateName: 'userPanel/index',
  model: function() {
    return this.store.filter("book", function(book) { return !book.get("isRead"); });
  },
  readBooks: false
});

App.UserPanelBooksSoldRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  templateName: 'userPanel/index',
  model: function() {
    return this.store.filter("book", function(book) { return book.get("isRead"); });
  },
  readBooks: true
});
```

Within the view I render the books and if there are no unread books I would like to display `"Sorry, no unread books"`, and if there are no read books I would like to display `"Sorry, no read books"` message. Except my method with setting a boolean in the route doesn't work (`readBooks` always evaluates to true in the view):

```
{{#if model.length}}
  {{#each book in model itemController='book'}}
    <ul>{{book.title}}</ul>
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  {{#if readBooks}}
    <h1>Sorry, no sold books</h1>
  {{else}}
    <h1>Sorry, no unsold books</h1>
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property in the `controller` not the `route`.

```
App.UserPanelBooksIndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  readBooks: false
});
```

I threw something together [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/luyumi/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

If it's an index, you will probably need to extend `Ember.ArrayController` instead of generic `Ember.Controller`

Comment: Totally forgot that each route has a corresponding controller. This works and thanks for the jsbin!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use setupController hook of route as well. your route will look like.

```
App.UserPanelBooksIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  templateName: 'userPanel/index',
  model: function() {
    return this.store.filter("book", function(book) { return !book.get("isRead"); });
  },
  setupController(controller,model){
  this._super(...arguments);
   controller.set('readBooks',false);
  }
});

App.UserPanelBooksSoldRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  templateName: 'userPanel/index',
  model: function() {
    return this.store.filter("book", function(book) { return book.get("isRead"); });
  },
  setupController(controller,model){
   this._super(...arguments);
   controller.set('readBooks',true);
  }
});
```